# String match and do the condition

Tags: bash, sh

When I try to match a string and do some conditions; it always fails to do so.

```
date=`date +%Y%m%d`
kol="/home/user/test_$date"
regex='Terminating the script'

if [ -f $kol ]; then

  sudo tail -f $kol | while read line; do 
     if [[  $line  = *"Terminating the"* ]]
     then

        echo "failed"

     else

        echo $line >> /home/user/test123_$date

     fi
else

   echo "File is not yet present"
   exit 0
fi
```

I have also tried with regex and that to failed. So when ever I input the matching string into the file ($path) it wont output "failed"; Is there anything wrong in the code. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: try putting then after ";" of if condition instead of next line and also add "" around $line , it should work fine

Comment: What does "fails to do so" actually mean? Do you get an error message? Can you provide sample input that can be tested with your script?
Note that `$path` is a reserved variable name. Consider testing your scripts at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) before posting, as well as doing your own syntax check with `bash -n yourscript.sh`

Comment: @priteshagrawal i tried those changes but it didn't work.

Comment: @ghoti I didn't get any error messages but never the expected output too; there are no errors in syntax.

Comment: @SajeeshKrishnan , what is the content of your file , can you please share , the lines which matches the condition.

Comment: Try adding `set -x` at the top of the script, and it'll print what it's doing as it runs. Add the output from when it tests the line that contains "Terminating the" to your question; it should clarify what's happening as the script runs.

Comment: `path` is not reserved; `PATH` is (or rather, it already has a special meaning and should not be used for your own purposes).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. At least it works for me:

```
sudo tail -f $1 | while read line; do

    if [[ $line = '' ]] 
    then
        break
    fi

    if [[  $line = *"Terminating the"* ]]
    then
        echo "failed"
    else
        echo $line >> /home/nurzhan/test123_$date
    fi
    done < "$1"
```

`$path` is parameter to the running script. Also note that by default the command `tail` returns only 10 last lines.

Comment: it didnt work; it always echo's "failed" when i run with the changes.

Comment: @SajeeshKrishnan What doe you input file contain? I checked the script it works for me fine.

Comment: Its a log file created for the date and when then log fails logs "Terminating the" it should match the regex and output the echo if not write the $line to the other file. Thanks!

Comment: @SajeeshKrishnan Let's clarify, if the line contains "Terminating the" then it should go to the file test123_$date? Or it is the other way round?

Comment: it's the other way around; if the $line contains "Terminating the"  it should echo "failed".

Comment: @SajeeshKrishnan, I checked my script on a simple input file and it worked as expected. Check yours more thoroughly.